# How to calculate a sensor size when all I know is focal length and resolution?

Tags: sensor, camera

A lot of the related questions require variables that we simply do not have. I would like to calculate sensor size for a video camera. We have focal length and resolution but I do not know the field of view or crop factor or any other additional camera information. Is there a way to calculate just from this? If I have to have something like field of view angle, can I calculate this without sensor size and then use it to find sensor size?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate sensor size (width and height) from focus length, vertical, and horizontal angle of view?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/87863/how-can-i-calculate-sensor-size-width-and-height-from-focus-length-vertical)

Comment: No. This requires knowing the angle of view. I do not know this. If there is a way to calculate this so that I can then use that to calculate sensor size, that would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need the sensor size?  How exact does it have to be?  Have you tried looking up the specs online?  Is the camera capable of taking stills?

Comment: Yes, it can take stills. Can I get sensor size from that? Unfortunately, the camera is a cheap amazon model and I cannot find specs for it and the seller won't respond. Sensor size is a requirement for a specific set of software used for analyzing video.

Comment: Have you tried taking stills and looking in the Exif?  There should be adequate info to *approximate* sensor size.  (focal length and 35mm equiv focal length)  You can use trial and error from there to find settings that work with your *video* analysis software.  More accurate info may be in the lensfun database if your camera and lens are supported.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot calculate sensor size from just focal length and resolution. Since resolution can vary depending on the sensor's construction, this just plain is not enough information.

If you have a scientific application, you should buy parts where the specifications are known. If it doesn't matter that much, you can measure the angle of view *in practice* from sample images of known objects, and then, since you know the focal length, work back from there.

Comment: "sample images of known objects" - such as measuring sticks.